# EditText.setError()'s popup message layout looks weird

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-toolbar

I use a `EditText` view inside my toolbar, and when the "check" icon is clicked, the app will check all fields are empty or not. If is empty, then `setError()` method is called. But the popup message looks strange (in the below figure).[image]

And I hide soft input, it looks like this. [image]

Another problem is that a `EditText` view is in the root layout, and when `setError()` is called, the view automatically scrolled up (`Appbarlayout` is hidden). How to let the layout correctly be below the view?[image]

Is this the layout design's problem?

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ActionbarStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_ItemName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/item_name"
                android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:textStyle="bold">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/layout_padding"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_money_black_24dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_Dollar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="end|right"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sort_black_24dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_SelectCategory"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="end|right|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/select_category" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_Note"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/background_border"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="@string/note"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/TextPAdding" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view_image_container"
                layout="@layout/layout_add_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widget_padding" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: for test case remove `<requestFocus />` than try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You Can use Snackbar as Validation which looks much better and have
  customization as u can show proper message for specific period of
  time... Example: on textChangedListener or On Button Click-->

  ```
   submitBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitBT);

         submitBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (loginET.getText().toString().isEmpty() || loginET.length() == 0 || loginET.length() > 50) {
             Snackbar.make(view, "Please Enter Username/Email", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;
         }
         if (passwordET.getText().toString().isEmpty() || passwordET.length() == 0 || passwordET.length() > 50) {
             Snackbar.make(view, "Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
             }
         });
  ```

  you can also use for textChangedListener...
  And the view will not automatically scrolled up like seterror

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question?